How do I split an animated gif into its individual images in Tcl/tk 8.4 or 8.6 with pure Tcl/Tk only
I'm working on some compatibility stuff with my freeware hurricane
tracker, JStrack, which has been based on Tcl/Tk 8.4 for a LONG time
(didn't know 8.6 was 100% backwards compatible, so now swapping out the 4
in 8.4 to 6 as in 8.6).
Anyways, part of the problem is breaking up animated gifs for GOES EAST
satellite imagery, one of which, the loop, is in the form of an animated
gif.  I've always used Img, but forgot over the decades that it has to be
compiled, and that's UNSAT, as I need JStrack to work "right out of the
box" after some simple automated configuration (autoconfig.tcl).  So I
need to split out the images without using Img or any other compiled
extensions.
I'm 99% certain that, decades and two cancers ago, I knew how to do this.
Now, however, I can't remember at all, other than there was a way with
(maybe the Tk canvas or somehow using a list?).  What I need to do is
download the imagery from GOES EAST, and if the user has selected the
"loop" image (animated gif), split that image into its parts and, using
the same frame rate as GOES EAST, display the gif frames in a Tcl/Tk
based player (that much is simple).  Here's what it looks like on GOES EAST:
https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/goes/fulldisk_band.php?sat=G16&band=GEOCOLOR&length=12
So, all of this boils down to this one question:  How do I split out the
frames from an animated gif using pure Tcl/Tk?
Thanks,
--jim
PS:  I'm fairly certain this is not the username I was using, but I lost
that, so this is the new one.
--
From my days in 16th Special Operations Wing Intelligence:
AN EXERCISE is a situation in which you stop what you're doing
in order to simulate doing what you were doing so you can show
someone else that you can simulate what you were doing as well
as you were doing it before you were interrupted.

There's a pseudo-option to the photo image format option for GIFs to let you select the frame index. I always have to look up the details. Once you have the image frame, you can save it out in any supported format.

Thanks.  That's exactly what I need ... and now that I know photo --> format --> ?, I should be able to find it.  Tomorrow.  I did plenty of other stuff today, until I hit the point where the low energy levels inflicted on me by cancer #1 said, "one more minute and you'll have eye migraines for days on end."  So I stopped.  :-)

A new search string slipped past my chemobrain this morning:
"animated gif tcl/tk".  It worked.  I found anigif.tcl by
Ryan Casey at https://cardtable.sourceforge.net/tcltk/
It looks like a simple package I can just slip right into JStrack
(with credit, obviously).  And it will work---I just finished
testing it.  All I need to do is get the actual size of the image
from GOES EAST and set the height/width of the label widget it
uses to the satellite image's dimensions.
So thanks anyways, but this seems to have solved itself once
chemobrain let one get away.  :-)
Seems every site is different...do I need to mark this solved or
does it just time out?
Thanks,
--jim
--
From my days in 16th Special Operations Wing Intelligence:
AN EXERCISE is a situation in which you stop what you're doing
in order to simulate doing what you were doing so you can show
someone else that you can simulate what you were doing as well
as you were doing it before you were interrupted.
